# Can multiple queries be issued in same connection?

Tags: database, database-connection

Can I issue multiple queries in the same connection or do I need to issue them 1 query per connection ?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what database and language you are working in?

Comment: ... and exactly what you mean by "connection?"

Answer (score 2):

All database API's that I've seen support multiple queries in the same connection. In fact, it's a good practice to keep your connection around if you are likely to have more queries soon.